# while loops that will never end

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, while-loop, break

How do i get my code to stop running the non stop 2.
what am i doing wrong with this addition i =+ 2;

```
using System;
namespace TestingNewShit
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= 14)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                i =+ 2;
                if (i ==15)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want `+=`, not `=+`

Comment: You'd think the IDE could point out that the unary `+` was unnecessary there...

Comment: `i =+ 2;` sets i to +2.

Comment: `=+` is _two separate operators_.  In this context, `+` is the [unary positive operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#unary-plus-and-minus-operators), rather than addition, and `=` is the assignment operator. With this combination, `+` has higher precedence and effectively results in a no-op. Then the value `2` is assigned to `i` on very iteration. Since `i` never exceeds `14`, the loop runs forever. What you meant to do was use the `+=` operator, which adds to `i` each time so the loop can end.

Comment: My bad my gents, but hats of to u to help this fool xoxo

Comment: And, for what it's worth, since `i` starts at 0 and you increment it by 2 over and over again (well, you intend to increment it by 2), this statement will never fire: `if (i ==15)`.  Yes, I realize you have `while (i <= 14)`, but, dead code is bad code

Comment: Yhea i was i figured that one my own a bit later out as i played around with it a bit, but again , Thank you VERY much to spend your time on me

Answer (score 1):

Should be i += 2, not  i =+ 2.
You are assigning (positive) 2, not adding 2.